# How to alter two fields at once in a Rust struct?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider the following simple example:

```
pub struct Bar {
    curr: Vec<i32>,
    prev: Vec<i32>,
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut b = Bar { curr: vec![1, 2, 3], prev: vec![2, 3, 4] };

    foo(&mut b);
}

pub fn foo(bar: &mut Bar) {
    let next = vec![3, 4, 5];

    bar.prev = bar.curr;
    bar.curr = next;
}
```

The use of `Vec` doesn't matter; the point is that `Bar` has two fields which don't implement `Copy`. This doesn't compile:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> derp.rs:15:16
   |
15 |     bar.prev = bar.curr;
   |                ^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

It's not hard to see why: by moving `bar.curr` without replacing it immediately, we have to move `bar` itself, which we're not allowed to do, as it's only borrowed mutably, not actually owned.

However this is a very common use case (in this case -- keeping the last two outputs of a function, for example) and I feel like there must be an idiomatic Rust use case. I realize this can be gotten around by using a single tuple `(curr, prev)` and assigning it at once, but (supposing the function `foo` was written long after the struct `Bar` has been in use) the refactoring could be pretty frustrating.

Assigning two values at once doesn't seem legal: the code `(bar.prev, bar.curr) = (bar.curr, next)` doesn't compile as the left side isn't a legal left-hand-side value.

It is somewhat interesting that the following code compiles:

```
pub struct Bar {
    curr: Vec<i32>,
    prev: Vec<i32>,
}

pub fn main() {
    let b = Bar { curr: vec![1, 2, 3], prev: vec![2, 3, 4] };

    foo(b);
}

pub fn foo(mut bar: Bar) -> Bar {
    let next = vec![3, 4, 5];

    bar.prev = bar.curr;
    bar.curr = next;

    bar
}
```

While the line `bar.prev = bar.curr` seems to *require* move privileges, it doesn't seem to *use* them, as the following line `bar.curr = next` shouldn't compile if `bar` has been moved.

Additionally, if you take the `bar.curr = next` line *out*, it no longer compiles (`bar` is returned after being moved), so it seems like the compiler is smart enough to figure out how to resolve this issue (that the fields all end up stably assigned), but can't do the same task for mutable pointers.

So I guess (a) is this a bug, (b) is this a *known* bug, and (c) is there a workaround so I can still do this with mutable pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) or [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html).

```
pub fn foo(bar: &mut Bar) {
    use std::mem;
    let next = vec![3, 4, 5];
    bar.prev = mem::replace(&mut bar.curr, next);
}
```

> It is somewhat interesting that the following code compiles [...]

This is because you own the structure, so the compiler can safely break it apart.  It can't do this when the structure is borrowed or behind some kind of pointer.  The key question is: what happens if you panic half-way through a modification (answer: it's possible code higher in the call stack could observe the invalid value, and Rust won't allow that to happen).

This isn't a bug, it's just how Rust works.

Comment: Pedantically, this doesn't allow you to modify two fields in the same struct *at once* — any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html):

```
pub fn foo(bar: &mut Bar) {
    let next = vec![3, 4, 5];

    std::mem::swap(&mut bar.prev, &mut bar.curr);
    bar.curr = next;
}
```

Comment: Pedantically, this doesn't allow you to modify two fields in the same struct *at once* — any ideas on how to do that?